# GoKart brake/flashers with 5-pin relay help

Tags: relay, automotive

I mistakenly bought 4-pin relays but think I may need a 5-pin relay for what I'm trying to do.  I bought a set of brake and turn LED's.

The intended operations is:  Key on, yellow turn signals.  Hit the brakes, applies power to white wire, removes power from yellow wire and allows "flashing" brake lights.

Red must have power to make all other LED functions operate.  You can not power yellow only and have it do turn signals.  You have to power both red and yellow to get the turn signal function.

If you apply power to red, white and yellow the turn signals prevail and only flashes amber.

Does my wiring look correct for what I'm thing to do?  Do I need a 5-pin relay or could I use 2, 4-pins some how (I have 4's on hand)?

[image: Diagram]

[image: LED diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like it will work, but I would change one thing. Relay pin 30 is connected directly to battery positive, so when the ignition is off there is still power going to the yellow wire. Since the module doesn’t work without power on red and that is ignition switched you should also have pin 30 ignition switched. This way the module doesn’t  get voltage on any wires until ignition is on.

You should also have the brake switch on ignition if it’s possible to wire it that way (as long as the switch is just for the lights). And everything should be properly fused.

If the ignition circuit can’t handle the current for all of it you can use it to activate a relay for switched battery power.

Comment: Good ideas.  I'll change the brake switch and 30 pin to the ignition.  Thank you.